What are some reliable US-based money transfer agents?
I am living in Europe, and my client can only transfer money to a US bank and US address. Is there any company that can serve as an agent to collect this money on my behalf, and later transfer it to my EU bank? To be clear, services like TransferWise or Payoneer do not satisfy these requirements.

That seems rather sketchy.  Particularly the "US address" bit.  Any US bank can wire money to someone in Europe.  And why wouldn't something like TransferWise work?  The only reasons I can come up with here is that the client is running some sort of scam or that you're trying to work around some legal requirement (i.e. the client can only hire a US employee and doesn't want an international transfer to exist that would show the client knew you were outside the US).

Or why can't they simply overnight you a check?

With or without Justin Cave's or David R's clearly relevant Comments, how would something such as PayPal not work for you?
